# for-loop is freezing screen even after use of promise function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, angular, for-loop

I have written this method which is computing 2 arrays of 1000's of data, which is fine as nothing can be done about the data but as the procedure starts, my whole screen freezes. I am using promise function in order to overcome this. But even then the screen is freezing.
(i have tried with forEach loop also, same freezing results). I need some way to escape freezing problem.

```
someClickEvent(arrayOfSelectedFile,eventArray){
 this.documentCorrection(arrayOfSelectedFile,eventArray)
 .then((response)=>{
    console.log(response);
  })
}

documentCorrection(arrayOfSelectedFile, eventArray) {    
  let somedata;
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfSelectedFile.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < eventArray.length; j++) {
          somedata = this.someFunctionGoinOn(arrayOfSelectedFile[i], eventArray[j] );         
        }
      } 
      resolve(somedata);        
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

Please note that this method gets resolved successfully. But during this for-loop procedure, screen is freezing.

Comment: It seems the computations are rather extensive, so you might want to look into WebWorkers to move those computations to a different thread.

Comment: updating... above one is just the schema of a real problem, i have resolved it.

Comment: you could use `Promise.race`

Comment: doesn't help! This is so frustrating. A good application looks bad because of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to return promise one by one and handle it. Use **Promise.all**. 
I manage my promise like this in loop. Check this. It might help you.

```
function awaitAll(count) {
  const promises = [];
  count = 10;
  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    promises.push(asyncFn()); // async operation
  }

  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: its my mistake that it lead you to think this, i am aware of `Promise.all`. What code i mentioned in the problem is just a schema of original function. I am resolving only once, at the end of both for-for loops.